# What system are these zip permissions from and what do they mean?

Tags: zip

I'm trying to implement some code to unzip a file and write its contents to the filesystem with the right permissions.  For most zip files, the external attributes are set to 0x040755 or 0x010644 and everything works fine.

However, a user [recently complained](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/518) that a certain zip file wasn't working for them and I took a look at it.  It looks like the zip has three different permissions it uses:

- `0x10` for directories.
- `0x20` for files.
- `0x26` for backup files (this is a guess, based on the filename).

I'm guessing this is Windows.  Is there any documentation about what numbers correspond to what on Windows-created zip files (or whatever system this is from)?

Comment: "The zip-file wasn't working for them" could mean anything. Maybe they just couldn't open it?

Comment: Um, no. If you look at the actual zip file in a hex editor, you can see that the external attributes section contains `004e6b50: 0000 0020 0000 0031 b529 0067 6c6d 2f64  ... ...1.).glm/d` (the `20 0000 00` is the external attributes I'm asking about).

Comment: [Related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14705/the-zip-formats-external-file-attribute)